# How to set active color of looped mat-cards?

Tags: angular, angular9, mat-card

I have a mat-card that is looped. How can i set the active color of the card that i clicked?

```
<div>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let tenant of tenantData">
  <mat-card class="card-card" (click)="onCardClick(tenant.id)">
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>{{tenant.tenantName}}</mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-subtitle>{{tenant.abbr}}</mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      Tenant# {{tenant.id}}
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable `activeTenantId` in `*component.ts` and onclick add current selected tenantId to this variable and add dynamic class

Example

```
<div>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let tenant of tenantData">
  <mat-card class="card-card" [class.active-tenant]="tenant.id === activeTenantId" (click)="onCardClick(tenant.id)">
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>{{tenant.tenantName}}</mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-subtitle>{{tenant.abbr}}</mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      Tenant# {{tenant.id}}
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</ng-container>
</div>

onCardClick(id) {
 activeTenantId = id; // <=== put your trigger here
}
```

Comment: It worked thanks. still need 6mins to accept your answer